# Insert the content of a text file in a job description

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to insert the content of a file inside a job description. My build generates a file and I can find it easily with the following URL: http:/[my-domain]job/[my-job]/lastBuild/artifact/[my-file]. In my case, this is a text file and I would like to display it in the job description. I can easily insert a link to this file with HTML but how can I insert the content of this file ?

Answer (score 1):

What is your Jenkins running on? Windows or Linux?

The [Project Description Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Project+Description+Setter+Plugin) is indeed the way to go, but you need to display the content of your file in the build log first, before the plugin will pick it up.

Like Christopher said, you don't need a job URL to access the file that you have in your workspace.

For Linux, put the following into your **shell execute** step:
`echo -n "[DESC] " && cat myfile`
For Windows, use this:
`echo|set /p="[DESC] " & type myfile`

This will print the content of file and prefix it with "[DESC]". We need this prefix (it can be anything you want) to identify this line to the Description Setter plugin

In the job configuration, under **Set build description**, type:
`\[DESC\]  (.*)`

One note: only the first line of the file will be printed in description

Answer (score 0):

The [Project Description Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Project+Description+Setter+Plugin) can do this.

Comment: Can you give some details ? I tried this plugin but I can't figure out how to make it working with URLs.

Comment: If you have the file in the workspace already, you don't need to refer to it by its artifact URL. Or if you do need to use a URL, just retrieve that URL into the workspace using `wget`, for example.